# Blank screen while adding subview in arc

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want a tabbarcontroller which should be inside a navigationcontroller. And i need to add it as the subview of my master page. Without ARC this code working fine. But a black screen appear when it is in ARC. help me please.

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate = self;

RestaurantListingClass *restList = [[RestaurantListingClass alloc]initWithNibName:@"RestaurantListingClass" bundle:Nil];

UITabBarItem *placeTab = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Places" image:nil tag:1];
    restList.tabBarItem = placeTab;

ReOrderVC *reorder=[[ReOrderVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ReOrderVC" bundle:Nil];

UITabBarItem *reorderTab = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Re-order" image:nil tag:1];
reorder.tabBarItem=reorderTab;

tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:restList,reorder, nil];

UINavigationController *navcontroller =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tabBarController];

DesignElementsClass *DEClass = [[DesignElementsClass alloc] init];
[DEClass setImageForsubNAvBar:navcontroller.navigationBar];
[DEClass setImageForsubTabBar:tabBarController.tabBar];
navcontroller.view.frame = view.bounds;

[self addChildViewController:navcontroller];
[self.view addSubview:navcontroller.view];
```

Comment: Is this the initial part of the app? i.e. is the nag controller the first thing the user will see?

Comment: no this will be in the intermediate portion

Comment: OK, so either way you shouldn't be just putting the navcontroller view onto the current view. You should present it modally or something. i.e. [self presentViewController:navcontroller animated:YES];

Comment: that cannot be done because i need to use the master page

Comment: If that's the case... you're doing it wrong. You shouldn't be restricted like this no matter how much you think you should be.

Comment: friend, in the question it very clearly i told you it working fine without arc. but i don't know why it not working in arc. that is only my doubt and i need clarification for that only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

ViewOne *firstView = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerOne"];
ViewTwo *secondView = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerTwo"];

UITabBarItem *placeTab = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Places" image:nil tag:1];
firstView.tabBarItem = placeTab;

UITabBarItem *reorderTab = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Re-order" image:nil tag:1];
secondView.tabBarItem=reorderTab;

tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstView,secondView, nil];

UINavigationController *navcontroller =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tabBarController];

[self addChildViewController:navcontroller];
[self.view addSubview:navcontroller.view];
```